# Form data won't bind to React component using onChange()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, jsx

I've been coding up an email service for myself, and got stuck on this React form not changing state when form data is entered. Tracked down the main problem to this React form not changing state via onChange()...

How could I bind state to the React form that updates on every keystroke? Using this form data to pass later into an API call.

'''
    class AddContact extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  'name': '',
  'company': '',
  'linkedin': '',
  'department': '',
  'email': 'Not available'
}

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

handleSubmit(event) {
}

render() {
return(
  <div>
    <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Name
      <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onchange = {this.handleChange}/>
    </label>
    <label>
      Company
      <input type="text" value={this.state.company} onchange = {this.handleChange}/>
    </label>
    <label>
      LinkedIn Profile
      <input type="text" value={this.state.linkedin} onchange = {this.handleChange}/>
    </label>
    <label>
      Department
      <input type="text" value={this.state.department} onchange = {this.handleChange}/>
    </label>
    <label>
      Email (Optional)
      <input type="text" value={this.state.email} onchange = {this.handleChange}/>
    </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
);

}
```

}
'''

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the actual form values in state. This line: `this.setState({ value: event.target.value });` Changes the value of the `value` key in the state. So if you were to call this `this.setState({ value: 'potato' });` then your state would look like this:

```
this.state = {
  'name': '',
  'company': '',
  'linkedin': '',
  'department': '',
  'email': 'Not available',
  'value': 'potato'
}
```

So you need to pass in the actual field name you're trying to change into the `onChange` function. And that's another thing, you have a typo. The handler is called `onChange`, with camel case. Yours is incorrectly all lower case.

So here's a correct example of updating the 'name' field. Firstly, update your `handleChange` function to this:

```
handleChange(field, value) {
     this.setState({ [field]: value });
}
```

Then change your inputs to be like this:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.handleChange('name', e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, apologies for my ignorance

Comment: @kkang2097 no worries. If this answered your question please mark this as the correct answer using the tick under the downvote arrow